# Fog, Amazon S3 and Carrierwave Rails issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

**UPDATED CONTENT**

My Setup is now as follows:

```
#Carrierwave Initializer

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
        :provider => 'AWS',
        :aws_access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
        :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'], 
    }
    config.fog_directory = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
    config.fog_public     = false  # optional, defaults to true
    config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}

end


#Uploader

class ProteinUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
   storage :fog

   def store_dir
      "images/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
   end

end


#Heroku Config Variables

S3_BUCKET_NAME = top5protein
S3_KEY = 'xxx'
S3_SECRET = 'xxx'


#Gemfile
...
gem "fog", "~> 1.14.0"
gem "excon", "~> 0.25.3"
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'activeadmin'
...
```

And the error I am still getting is:

```
Excon::Errors::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
2013-07-28T11:51:13.251291+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/excon-0.25.3/lib/excon/connection.rb:260:in `rescue in request'
2013-07-28T11:51:13.251455+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/excon-0.25.3/lib/excon/connection.rb:220:in `request'
2013-07-28T11:51:13.251056+00:00 app[web.1]: FYyKoH99bOV97aK1TQI9dEhIBycFUg2TyP2fYuzY1/Ke+TXevyjKlUA</HostId><SignatureProvided>ZuHHwrD3Qdo9IHNhE14eKiB0OgY=</SignatureProvided><StringToSign>PUT\n\nimage/png\nSun, 28 Jul 2013 11:51:12 +0000\nx-amz-acl:private\n/top5protein/images/general/image/2/Protein1.png</StringToSign><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJ5GKDLKK3CPHNTGA</AWSAccessKeyId></Error>", @headers={"x-amz-request-id"=>"04AD4FA1DDE488CE", "x-amz-id-2"=>"SkpxPPpk0FYyKoH99bOV97aK1TQI9dEhIBycFUg2TyP2fYuzY1/Ke+TXevyjKlUA", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Date"=>"Sun, 28 Jul 2013 11:51:12 GMT", "Connection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, @status=403, @remote_ip="207.171.163.195">):
```

and

```
HNTGA</AWSAccessKeyId></Error>", :headers=>{"x-amz-request-id"=>"04AD4FA1DDE488CE", "x-amz-id-2"=>"SkpxPPpk0FYyKoH99bOV97aK1TQI9dEhIBycFUg2TyP2fYuzY1/Ke+TXevyjKlUA", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Date"=>"Sun, 28 Jul 2013 11:51:12 GMT", "Connection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, :status=>403, :remote_ip=>"207.171.163.195"}, @body="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 70 6e 67 0a 53 75 6e 2c 20 32 38 20 4a 75 6c 20 32 30 31 33 20 31 31 3a 35 31 3a 31 32 20 2b 30 30 30 30 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3a 70 72 69 76 61 74 65 0a 2f 74 6f 70 35 70 72 6f 74 65 69 6e 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 67 65 6e 65 72 61 6c 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 32 2f 50 72 6f 74 65 69 6e 31 2e 70 6e 67</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>04AD4FA1DDE488CE</RequestId><HostId>SkpxPPpk0
```

If anyone has any further advice that might help then that would be great!

Comment: Check that you've got the latest versions of fox & exxon. there have been some odd interactions with some of the versions recently

Comment: Hey Fred, Thanks for your reply - where can I check these versions?

Comment: they'll be in your Gemfile.lock, but I can see from the paths in that backtrace that fog isn't the latest version

Comment: Thanks again, I am updating this now so hopefully it will work. Do you know if by default AWS S3 users have any permissions or will I need to write these also?

Comment: Unless you've been creating IAM users you'll have full access already.

Comment: It appears to be a signature mismatch `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error. Which doesn't mean anything about credentials, it means that the signature was not constructed correctly, which is probably a fog bug. There have been some recent fixes to that, so an update is probably a good first step as Frederick mentioned.

Comment: Hey Geemus, Thanks for your reply. It started working when I upgraded to Excon 0.25.3 and included a 'T' that was stupidly missing from my S3_SECRET :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case (as noted in the last comment) and in mine, the reason for this error was an incorrect secret key.

I thought I'd leave this here for future people getting this error so they could check the most probable source of the problem first.